# How does convexity imply that $(1-a)^{-q}\ge1+qa$?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let $q>0$ and $$f(a):=(1-a)^{-q}\;\;\;\text{for }a\in(-\infty,1).$$ I've read that convexity of $f$ implies that $$f(a)\ge1+qa\;\;\;\text{for all }a\in[0,1)\tag1.$$ How do we see this?

It's clear to me that $f$ is actually convex, since $f''(a)=q(q+1)(1-a)^{-(q+2)}$ for all $a\in(-\infty,1)$.

Comment: It's the tangent line at the origin, and being above the tangent line is sorta the idea of convexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1+qa$ is the tangent line to $f$ at $a = 0$. Convex functions lie above their tangent lines.

Answer (score 0):

We have the equality
$$(1+a)^{-q} = 1 + q a + \frac{q(q+1)}{2} a^2 + \cdots + \frac{q(q+1)\ldots (q+n-1)}{n!} a^n + \cdots $$
valid for $|a|< 1$.

If $q > 0$ and $a\in [0,1)$, any partial sum will give a lower estimate.

(see the calculation in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=TaylorSeries%5B%281-a%29%5E%28-q%29%2C%20%7Ba%2C0%2C10%7D%5D))